# How to preserve cake php controller changes?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I have baked a project in cakephp. I have done custom modification in the controller, when I bake the code again those changes are lost.
Is there any way to keep those changes? 
I am new in cakephp please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you keep the files in the app directory you will loose those changes because the Bake Console will override them.

What can you do then? Well you could:

1. bake inside a new app (just connect to the same DB) and then merge the changes with your existing Controllers. For merging you could use [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/download.html) - a very nice and small footprint merge editor which works on almost all OSs (Linux, Mac OS, BSD and Windows).
2. back up your existing application and bake over it. Then merge the changes you've done back to the application.

It should be better to use method 1. if your changes are more code than the parts that you wish to bake.
This could be a nice add-on to the existing console's functionality.  Maybe via a diff from the original baked version and the current changed one. However I am not sure if this is needed, since the idea is to initially bake and then develop.

Comment: Thanks @Borislav for your answer, but It would be very tedious task because I am having 45-50 Controller and taking diff and making changes to all will be very difficult. I am looking for a solution that I can put my code at common place or something like that.

Comment: If it's just some (1-10) controllers you do not have any other option. Just preserve your current code-state and merge your changes back to the newly baked code. I saw that in a comment you mentioned you need to copy only one function? If that is the case then you don't have a big problem. The other way is to bake in a separate app and merge the newly backed code into your existing app.

Comment: Ya..I agree but I would keep this option for last because 30-35 of my controllers are having 4-5 functions define by me. I want a complete solution for it or some way how can I develop it.

Comment: This is the only way. The other option is to just manually code the functionality you wish to bake.

Comment: Use abstract base classes with well known interface and extend your real controllers. Keep code inside base classes. Not completely automagick at this point but should be easily `perl'able` to be. And at least merging will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to Bake new controllers and don't want to overwrite your existing controllers, instead of using "bake all", you could use "bake controller". It would then prompt you for which model to use for the Bake.

Comment: My Problem is, I have created a controller and I have added a login function, when I bake that controller again my login function is lost but I do not want to loose it.